# Alarm being called instantaneously when time set to 0:00

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-alarms, android-calendar

I am making an alarm that activates like any other alarm on the hour and minute that the user selects. I found a problem when the time is set at 0:00 the alarm activates immediately.

I have a custom `AlarmManager` in which I call schedule repeating like this:

```
CustomAlarmManager alarmManager = new CustomAlarmManager(getActivity());
alarmManager.scheduleRepeatingAlarm(getActivity(),
    alarmID, alarmHour, alarmMinute);
```

And for the problematic example these values are being passed:

```
Id = 619
Hour = 0
Minute = 0
```

This is the `setRepeatingAlarm()` function:

```
public void scheduleRepeatingAlarm(Context context, int alarmID, int hour, int minute) {
    System.out.println("schedule is running");
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmNotificationReciever.class);
    Bundle extras = new Bundle();
    extras.putBoolean(KEY_REPEAT, true);
    extras.putInt("AlarmId", alarmID);
    intent.putExtras(extras);
    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,
        alarmID, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

    Calendar calender = Calendar.getInstance();
    calender.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
    calender.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
        setSingleExactAlarm(calender.getTimeInMillis(), pIntent);
    } else {
        mAlarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
            calender.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pIntent);

    }
}
```

I am assuming the problem is going to be with these lines here:

```
Calendar calender = Calendar.getInstance();
calender.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
calender.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
```

And this line when setting the alarm:

```
setSingleExactAlarm(calender.getTimeInMillis(), pIntent);
```

For ever other hour and minute combination it seems to work and treat it as a time to go off. But for hour = 0 and minute = 0 it just fires straight away.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: The problem is the day. If you set the hour to 0:00, the system will ring for the same day. You have to add one day to fire at the next day at 0:00. It fires directly because alarms will fire if the set time is passed.....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the expected behaviour.

`Calendar.getInstance()` returns a `Calendar` instance set to the current date/time.

Leaving the date untouched and setting the hour and minute fields to `0` effectively sets the alarm in the past (it is considered a missed alarm).

From the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setRepeating(int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent)) of `setRepeating()`:

> **If the stated trigger time is in the past, the alarm will be triggered
>   immediately**, with an alarm count depending on how far in the past the
>   trigger time is relative to the repeat interval.

You could do something like this to perform a check:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);

Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();

if(calendar.before(now)) {
    // handle this as you wish

    // adding a day to calendar
    calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
}
```